# icacls function not overwriting the previous directory permissions

Tags: windows, batch-file, permissions, folder-permissions, icacls

I am using the following code:

```
icacls C:\testscott\ /grant:r "TestGroup":(NP)F
```

However, the existing permissions in the directory C:\testscott\ are still there. I thought using the /grant:r option meant it would overwrite the existing permissions?

Comment: You're adding an ACE that should [r]eplace an existing ACE for "TestGroup", but not removing inherited rights. I don't know how to combine operations with icacls. I'd use 3 passes. Copy inherited ACLs and disable inheritance: `icacls C:\testscott /inheritance:d`. Remove any ACEs for "TestGroup": `icacls C:\testscott /remove "TestGroup"`. Add the desired ACE: `icacls C:\testscott\ /grant "TestGroup":(NP)F`.

Comment: Note that even that won't remove existing explicit permissions for *other* users and groups.  To do that you need the `/reset` option, or use `cacls`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To replace all permissions on a directory with newly assigned ones:

```
icacls c:\test /reset
icacls c:\test /inheritance:r /grant Administrators:(OI)(CI)(F)
```

Comment: I didn't know whether Scott was looking to replace inherited permissions for only TestGroup with an explicit ACE or to replace all inherited permissions. I assumed the former, and I wasn't able to do it in fewer than 3 passes. I was surprised that `grant:r` didn't work after copying via `inheritance:d`. Either way, I voted to close this question as off topic. It belongs on superuser.com.

Comment: Apparently on the 2nd pass, even though `grant:r` doesn't work I can combine `/remove TestGroup` and `/grant TestGroup` in one operation. But that looks like undefined behavior to me, or at least poorly defined behavior.

Comment: @eryksun: not off-topic in my opinion because `icacls` is how you change permissions in batch files.  (And it is predominantly used in programming, because most people use the GUI for interactive permissions changes rather than the command line.)

Comment: It looks like a system administration question to me. For sure, shell scripting for administrative tasks is a grey area, but to me this falls closer to superuser's domain, such as [this question](http://superuser.com/q/87028).

Comment: @eryksun: that would make all batch questions either off-topic or ill-conceived, wouldn't it?  :-)  The Windows batch processor is designed for administrative tasks, not for general-purpose programming.  Now, I'd personally have a certain amount of sympathy for the proposition that batch programming should be automatically off-topic here, but precedent says otherwise. :-)

Comment: I don't think batch programming is generally off topic (indeed it's such a weird and limited language that people need all the help they can get). Certainly a script that programmatically administers a computer is a program all the same. But this question is more about using the icacls tool, not about batch programming.

Comment: @eryksun: yeah, but the icacls tool is a "software tool used primarily by programmers" - if you accept that writing batch scripts is programming.  Everybody *else* just uses the GUI.  (Well, almost everybody.)

Comment: (And in particular if you posted such a question to Super User or Server Fault you're likely to get answers that say "don't do that, just use the GUI".)

Comment: Command-line programs may be cryptic and difficult for the average Windows user, but that doesn't automatically make using them a kind of programming. Using them involves no variables, no logic/branching, no iteration/recursion, no algorithms. You just set some 'switches' and press the 'on button' (enter).

Comment: @eryksun: no, using icacls on the command line is not programming.  But (a) the OP is using it in a batch script, which *is* programming; and (b) that's (probably, and IMO) the most common use case.  (And for the windows tag, at least, I think the established precedent is that using command-line utilities in batch files is considered on-topic.  That's based solely on my unreliable memory of prior questions, of course.)